# Compare two mysql tables and display changes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called archive:

```
| staff_id |   longname  | username | projectNo |  title   | process | creation_time |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ch) |  2017-01-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | BGD(ch) |  2017-03-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-03-16   |  
|    03    | James Bond  |   James  |    1702   | project2 | BGD(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
|    03    | Peter Parker|   Peter  |    1702   | project2 | BAD(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
```

I want to take rows with min date from table:

```
SELECT staff_id, longname, username, title, process, creation_time FROM archived
WHERE creation_time IN (SELECT min(creation_time) FROM archived)
```

And rows with latest date:

```
SELECT staff_id, longname, username, title, process, creation_time FROM archived
WHERE creation_time IN (SELECT max(creation_time) FROM archived)
```

Then I want to compare received tables and dispaly only that rows which changed and appeared. So from current table I want to get only:

```
| staff_id |   longname  | username | projectNo |  title   | process | creation_time |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | BGD(ch) |  2017-03-16   |
|    03    | James Bond  |   James  |    1702   | project2 | BGD(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
|    03    | Peter Parker|   Peter  |    1702   | project2 | BAD(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
```

is there any way to do it in single query? if not how can it be done in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to do a `right join`

```
SELECT  t2.*
FROM    (
            SELECT  staff_id, longname, username, title, process, creation_time
            FROM    archived
            WHERE   creation_time IN (SELECT min(creation_time) FROM archived)
        ) t1
RIGHT JOIN (
            SELECT  staff_id, longname, username, title, process, creation_time
            FROM    archived
            WHERE   creation_time IN (SELECT max(creation_time) FROM 
        ) t2
ON      t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id AND
        t1.projectNo = t2.projectNo AND
        t1.process = t2.process
WHERE   t1.staff_id is null
```

The right join will preserve all the results from the second table (the one with the max) and give them `null`s on the first table's columns if they don't match. This way you can filter on any of the first table columns being `null` to get only the rows that don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a  left join between the max result table and the min result table

```
select t1.* from ( 
  SELECT staff_id, longname, username, title, process, creation_time FROM archived
  WHERE creation_time IN (SELECT max(creation_time) FROM archived)
) t1
left join (
  SELECT staff_id, longname, username, title, process, creation_time FROM archived
  WHERE creation_time IN (SELECT min(creation_time) FROM archived)
) t2 on t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id and t1.creation_time = t2.creation_time
where t2.creation_time is null
```